# How to rerun CompositeSubscription with ReplaySubject?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I have CompositeSubscription , and there I add Subscription with ReplaySubject

```
 CompositeSubscription compositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
    ReplaySubject subject = ReplaySubject.create();

 compositeSubscription.add(
                manager.getAllContacts()
                .toList()
                .doOnNext(new Action1<List<Person>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(List<Person> persons) {
                        allPersons = persons;
                        Log.e(TAG, "BookContacts: " + "allPersons = " + allPersons.size());
                        setupViewPager();
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(subject));
```

then I add second Subscription with this ReplaySubject

```
compositeSubscription.add(Observable.combineLatest(subject,
                                                           (PublishSubject<List<CustomUser>>) execute(
                                                                   manager.getDigitsContacts()),
                                                           new Func2<List<Person>, List<CustomUser>, Object>() {
                                                               @Override
                                                               public Object call(List<Person> persons, List<CustomUser> customUsers) {
                                                                  //... my code with persons and customUsers...
                                                                   return null;
                                                               }
                                                           })
                                            .subscribe());
```

code is working, after that complete ReplaySubject hasCompleted  = true.

but when I try to add third Subscription , it doesn't call "call()" method

```
compositeSubscription.add(Observable.combineLatest(subject,
                                                           (PublishSubject<List<CustomUser>>) execute(
                                                                   manager.getFacebookContacts()),  //<-----manager.getFacebookContacts() is run, but doesn't call call() method
                                                           new Func2<List<Person>, List<CustomUser>, Object>() {
                                                               @Override
                                                               public Object call(List<Person> persons, List<CustomUser> customUsers) {
                                                                  //...this method is not called after  "manager.getFacebookContacts()"
                                                                   return null;
                                                               }
                                                           })
                                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                                            .subscribe());
```

HOW TO SOLVE IT?...Because if I add Subscription simultaneously it works fine.

Comment: In the first code snippet it looks like, instead of doing side effects in `doOnNext` you need an `Observable` of all contacts. You could then subscribe to it and update view pager accordingly. Probably you want `BehaviorSubject` instead of `ReplySubject`. It's hard for me to understand what you want to achieve, please describe it.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please add error callback to `.subscribe()`? My guess is that the third time, `ReplaySubject` overflows the combineLatest's buffer. Instead of creating a subject, you should use `.replay().autoConnect(0)`

CompositeSubscription compositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();

```
Observable<List<Person>> persons = manager.getAllContacts()
    .toList()
    .doOnNext(new Action1<List<Person>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(List<Person> persons) {
            allPersons = persons;
            Log.e(TAG, "BookContacts: " + "allPersons = " + allPersons.size());
            setupViewPager();
        }
    }).replay().autoConnect(0, s -> compositeSubscription.add(s));
```

Then use `persons` instead of `subject`